# difference between "sh -c" and "sh -s" in linux

Tags: shell

can anyone explain the difference between sh -c and sh -s in linux with some examples?
I read the sh man page but i don't get the difference.

Comment: What does the man page say about those options? What did happen when you tried them? What part in particular is there that you don't get?

Comment: It's somehow confusing for me.I know maybe it sounds silly and easy to understand but i didn't get this sentence in the man page. I mean the last one.                        "If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. ((If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0))"

Answer (score 1):

One is an argument on the command line:

```
sh -c 'sh executes this string as a command'
```

The other is a string passed via the standard input:

```
echo 'sh executes this string as a command' | sh -s
```

Comment: Thanks, I have two more questions. 1-Is there difference between using these two if we want to use arguments? 2-how can we run script in docker run command with this?                            e.g:docker run -i --name container_name centos < script.sh  I know this but i want to know if we could use sh to run script